# sql where clause variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA and SQL. My VBA looks like

```
Dim SystemLookup As String
Dim SqlString As String


If IsNull(Me!SystemLookup) Then
   Me!SystemLookup = ""
Else
    SystemLookup = Me!SystemLookup
End If

SqlString = "SELECT TblField.*, TblOrigin.SystemID" _
        & " FROM TblField INNER JOIN TblOrigin ON TblField.OriginID = TblOrigin.OriginID " _
        & " WHERE (((TblOrigin.SystemID) = " & systemlookup )) ""

Me.RecordSource = SqlString
End Sub
```

I have my bracketing on the where clause is wrong but I am not sure how to fix. Any sugguestions (Systemlookup is a variable that is being passed from a form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the brackets **inside** the string, not besides the variable.

Try this:

```
SqlString = "SELECT TblField.*, TblOrigin.SystemID" _
            & " FROM TblField INNER JOIN TblOrigin ON TblField.OriginID = TblOrigin.OriginID " _
            & " WHERE (((TblOrigin.SystemID) = " & systemlookup  & ")) "
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ampersand and a double quote and have an extra opening bracket.  The brackets are not needed in this simple query.

```
SqlString =  "SELECT TblField.*, TblOrigin.SystemID" _
        & " FROM TblField INNER JOIN TblOrigin ON TblField.OriginID = TblOrigin.OriginID " _
        & " WHERE TblOrigin.SystemID = " & systemlookup  & ";"
```

You would bracket WHERE clauses when you need to group conditions.
For example if you wanted to know if a product was shipped between two dates or if the product wasn't shipped then you would bracket it.

All three of these examples are valid:

> WHERE ([Shipped Date]>=#10/28/2017# AND [Shipped Date]<=#10/30/2017#) OR [Shipped Date] is Null
>
> WHERE ([Shipped Date]>=#10/28/2017# AND [Shipped Date]<=#10/30/2017#) OR ([Shipped Date] is Null)
>
> WHERE (([Shipped Date]>=#10/28/2017# AND [Shipped Date]<=#10/30/2017#) OR ([Shipped Date] is Null))